# Using Google Maps website to create a keyless Embedded map

Tags: google-maps-embed

I notice that, if I follow the instructions on [this google maps answer](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/144361), there is no information about the requirement for an API key when embedding a Google Map iframe into the HTML of my website or blog.

What will be the requirements for this sort of use regarding keyless embedded maps access following June 11?

Answer (score 0):

None I suppose,

I'm using ruby explaining the code below

```
<iframe ... src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=#{question}&z=15&ie=UTF8&iwloc=&output=embed" ... ></iframe>
```

So far this is working (Aug 30) and should be working for a while since it's the Maps way to share addresses. This embed forces a couple logos related to Google like, Maps Embed API (free but not keyless)

If you plan to use Maps as a developer with other options please consider registering an API in Google cloud.
Meanwhile, you could use it like you are using it.